# Trying to get property 'RmFName' of non-object

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm getting the following error:

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

The following is DB:

```
roomfloor
-RmFID (PK)
-RmFName (FK)
roomtype
-RmTypeID (PK)
-RmTypeBed 
-RmTypeRent 
-RmFName (FK)
```

The following is my code:

**Models:**

```
class RoomType extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'RmTypeID';
    protected $table = 'roomtype';
    protected $fillable = ['RmTypeID','RmTypeBed','RmTypeRent','RmFName'];
    public function roomfloors(){
   return $this->belongsTo(RoomFloor::class,'RmFName','RmFName');
    }
}


class RoomFloor extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'RmFID';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'roomfloor';
    protected $fillable =['RmFID','RmFName'];
    public function roomtypes(){
            return $this->hasOne(RoomType::class,'foreign_key', 'RmFName');
    }
}


public function index()
{
    $roomtype = RoomType::with('roomfloors')->get();
    return view('roomtype.index',[
        'roomtypes'=>$roomtype
    ]);
}
```

**Template:**

```
@foreach ($roomtypes as $roomtype)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $roomtype->RmTypeID}}</td>
        <td>{{ $roomtype->RmTypeBed}}</td>
        <td>{{ $roomtype->RmTypeRent}}</td>
        <td>{{ $roomtype->roomfloor->RmFName }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your template for `RmFName` before you call it:

```
@foreach ($roomtypes as $roomtype)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $roomtype->RmTypeID}}</td>
        <td>{{ $roomtype->RmTypeBed}}</td>
        <td>{{ $roomtype->RmTypeRent}}</td>
        @if($roomtype->roomfloor)
        <td>{{ $roomtype->roomfloor->RmFName }}</td>
        @else
        <td>No thing found</td>
        @endif
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

This error come when the ORM relationship is break.
means,
1. checkout the both table if one of RmFName is missing in other table then its break the property and this error come.
so,you can check out that all record present to other table of foreign key RmFName in second table.
2. if one of record is miss then its error come's.